# How to prevent loops in cubic Bezier curves

Tags: loops, curve, bezier

I have a calculation that produces a cubic 2D Bezier curve. In this situation, the endpoints are fixed and my program calculates the internal control points. Most of the time these curves produce simple blends between two nearby shapes. But sometimes the geometry is such that drawing the curve would produce a loop, which would never look good in this application. In such situations, I am willing to modify the control points to prevent the loop. But to do this, I need to detect whether the given cubic Bezier curve will loop when drawn.

I could of course simply sample the curve at many points and look for a loop, but I'd rather find an algebraic solution based on the 8 variables (x and y values for each of the 4 points). Ideally, that solution will tell me not just if there's a loop, but how "big" the loop is in some sense. But even having a binary yes/no answer would be a big help.

Does anyone know of an algorithm that can determine if a given cubic 2D Bezier curve will produce a loop when drawn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

certainly: you can look at its [canonical form](http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#canonical) to see whether the four points result in the curve "ending" in a region where loops must necessarily exist.

The original theory for this is outlined in the 1989 paper ["A Geometric Characterization of Parametric Cubic curves"](http://graphics.pixar.com/people/derose/publications/CubicClassification/paper.pdf)

Comment: Thank you, Pomax, I forgot about that great classic paper. It's exactly what I needed. Your Bezier reference page is absolutely excellent: you've gathered a vast amount of useful information about Bezier curves and explained it all beautifully. Thank you for creating and sharing it.

Answer (score 0):

First the code, some explanation later. The process is somewhat time-consuming, so the code was slighty optimized. Now it resembles a sharp selection, where very few candidates will pass all tests.

```
type
  myType=Integer; {remember to change here to your own type, 
    an integers are good for an educational purpose}
  point_2d=record    xx,yy :myType  end;
  vector_2d=record    vx,vy :myType  end;    

function bezier_has_a_loop(p0,p1,p2,p3:point_2d):boolean;
              {-------------------------}
              function f_vec_from_2_pts(pa,pb:point_2d):vector_2d;
              begin
                with Result do begin
                  vx:=pb.xx - pa.xx;
                  vy:=pb.yy - pa.yy     end  end;
              {-------------------------}
              function f_cross_prod(va,vb : vector_2d):myType;
              begin
                 Result := va.vx*vb.vy - va.vy*vb.vx      end;
              {-------------------------}
              function f_mult(m:myType; v:vector_2d):vector_2d;
              begin
                with Result do begin
                  vx := m*v.vx;
                  vy := m*v.vy   end   end;
              {-------------------------}
              function f_sum(va,vb : vector_2d):vector_2d;
              begin
                with Result do begin
                  vx := va.vx+vb.vx;
                  vy := va.vy+vb.vy    end   end;
              {-------------------------}
              function f_rotate(v, rotor : vector_2d):vector_2d;
              var
                m_sin,m_cos:myType; {only for a readability purpose}
              begin
                m_cos:=rotor.vx {
                /sqrt(sqr(rotor.xx)+sqr(rotor.yy))  - unnecessary };
                m_sin:=rotor.vy {
                /sqrt(sqr(rotor.xx)+sqr(rotor.yy))  - unnecessary };
                with Result do begin
                  vx := -v.vx * m_cos - v.vy *m_sin;
                  vy :=  v.vx * m_sin - v.vy *m_cos   end   end;
              {-------------------------}
var
  a,b,c, c1,c2,c3  :vector_2d;
  ab,ac,bc:myType;
  bb,s1,s2,delta,shift,t_1_2 : Double;
begin

  a:=f_vec_from_2_pts(p0,p1);
  b:=f_vec_from_2_pts(p1,p2);
  c:=f_vec_from_2_pts(p2,p3);

  ab:=f_cross_prod(a,b); {on the planar, 
    myType for a cross product is just fine}}
  ac:=f_cross_prod(a,c);
  bc:=f_cross_prod(b,c);

  {==1== No inflection point(s) or cusp allowed}
  if ac*ac >= 4*ab*bc  then begin    Result:=False; exit end;

  c3:= f_sum( f_sum(a,c)  ,  f_mult( -2,b ) );
  if c3.vy<>0 then begin   {Is the bag's handle horizontal?}
    a := f_rotate(a,c3);      
    b := f_rotate(b,c3);
    c := f_rotate(c,c3);
    c3:= f_sum  ( f_sum(a,c) , f_mult(-2,b) ); 
    {Now the handle is forced to be horizontal.}
  end;

  c1:= f_mult ( 3,a );
  c2:= f_sum  ( f_mult(3,b) , f_mult(-3,a) );

  { Following 4 restrictions comes from a single caveats for a roots:
     0<= t1<t2<=1}
  bb:= -c1.vy / c2.vy;  { always  c2.vy<>0 }

  {==2== A central point (t1+t2)/2 outside the limits}
  if  (bb<0) or  (bb>2) then begin Result:=False;  exit  end;

  s1:= c1.vx/c3.vx;    { always  c3.vx<>0 }
  s2:= c2.vx/c3.vx;
  delta := -bb*(4*s2+3*bb)-4*s1;

  {==3==  delta is to big}
  if delta>1 then begin Result:=False;  exit  end;

  shift:=sqrt(delta);   { always  delta>0 }
  t_1_2:=bb-shift;    {for readability purpose only, 
    one can omit this and write below: if shift>bb }

  {==4==  t1 is to low }
  if t_1_2<0 then begin Result:=False; exit end;
  t_1_2:=bb+shift;      { no /2 here,beacause of *2 below}

  {==5==  t2 is to high}
  if t_1_2>2 then  Result:=False
              else  Result:=True  { TA DA! Thank you for your patience. }
end;
```

Now some theory.

1. Let take into account 4 points P0, P1, P2, P3. These points define (almost always) a cubic Bézier curve.
2. Let establish the point H1 such as the vector P1_H1 is half of the vector P0_P1.
3. Let establish the point H2 such as the vector P2_H2 is half of the vector P3_P2.
4. At the end, let create the vetor *h* = H1_H2.  (Personally I call this vector "the handle of the bag", guess why.)

[Bezier curve and its handle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWksC.png)

- No surprise here, when you start an isotropic scaling or a roation of P0, P1, P2, P3, then vector *h* will transform accordingly.
- Maybe for someone this will be a surprise, the vector *h* = [_h_x,_h_y]  is proportional to the vector [c3x,c3y] created from the highest coefficients of the algebraic form of the cubic Bézier curve. The  proportionality coefficient is (-1/2).

(In fact, when the points H1=H2 coincide, the *h* vector vanishes, c3x=c3y=0, thus the cubic Bézier curve reduces at least into the quadratic Bézier curve, created from P0,H1,P3 points.)

And now the clue: The right rotation can always turn the vector *h* horizontally (or verically), and this rotation will reduce c3y ( or c3x ) into null, however preserving the loop. In turn, one can reduce the stated problem into a trivial root-finding of a quadratic equation. (I suppose this is a decisive hint to find a solution.)

To measure the loop, I suggest take into account the variable *delta* from the code above.

```
   0 < delta <= 1
When delta -> 0, the loop vanishes. 
When delta -> 1, the loop becomes really pompous.
```

I'm not quite happy with this proposal, but it is still better than nothing.